# Debug PHP on Eclipse MARS with XDebug: error: file does not exist

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, debugging, xdebug

I am trying to follow the instructions on [this page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug). I am trying to configure Eclipse for PHP, Mars Release (4.5.0), to use XDebug so I can set breakpoints in my PHP code and track variables. Here is what I have done so far:

> C:\xampp\php\php.ini:
>
> uncomment: zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
>
> uncomment and set: xdebug.remote_enable = 1
>
> restart Apache
>
> In Eclipse, check out Windows | Preferences | PHP | Debug.
>
> Click on the Debug icon, go to Debug Configurations | PHP Web
>   Application and set XDebug as the debugger.

However, in the debug configurations, I am unable to set the server. I am using the latest version of XAMPP on Windows 7. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

What is wrong with my configuration and why am I getting the red [X] in the server configuration window? The only available menu entry from the drop-down menu is 'Default PHP Web Server'.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on your **index.php** and select **Debug As | PHP Web Application** from the drop down menu. This will automatically create the server configuration.